# what is the correct way of assigning vue state (ref()) to each other?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ref, vue-composition-api

I am a little confused about using ref() in vue 3 (script setup) because of the ref().value.
what I want to know is should I use ref().value = ref().value or ref()=ref() I provide an example:

```
<script setup>
let stateOne=ref('1')
let stateTwo=ref('2')

//This way:
stateOne.value=stateTwo.value

//Or this:
stateTwo=stateOne

</script>
```

thank you for helping me understand this concept better

Comment: The first way is correct. The second won't even compile because `stateTwo` is `const`, so it can't be reassigned. It seems like you could've arrived at that answer just by trying it :)

Comment: you are right but what if it's let stateOne

Comment: You mean `let stateTwo`? Then, `stateTwo=stateOne` would make `stateTwo` refer to `stateOne`'s `ref`, and you'd lose the `ref` that `stateTwo` was originally assigned to. See Daniel's answer below.

Comment: I can't think of a reason to use reassignment (instead of just the same variable), I'm sure there are instances where that may be a reasonable solution, but if you're asking this question, you almost certainly are looking to do assignment via `value`

Comment: honestly this confusion came from the fact that we don't use .value in template I know it may seem unrelevent but it made me wonder maybe another ref is somhow aware that  stateOne.value should go in stateTwo.value, and Im trying to understand the concept better and you are right about reassignment in this form is not needed in most cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Assign value (correct way)

```js
stateOne.value = stateTwo.value;
```

This will make the values equal, so if you change `stateOne.value`, `stateTwo.value` will remain the same.

#### Reassign the variable

```js
stateTwo = stateOne;
```

*Will only work if `stateTwo` is defined with `let`* and
will make the variables the same, so if `stateOne.value` is set to "something" `stateTwo.value` will also be updated

Comment: thank you for your answer I edited my question code so my mistake don't make this question confusing and straight